# Should I prefer to iterate over Map.entries or Map.values?

Tags: dart

Every time I need to iterate over the values of a `Map` in Dart, I contemplate the cost that this loop will incur, in terms of the complexity and the amount of garbage produced. There are two ways to iterate over the values of a `Map`: `Map.values`, and `Map.entries`. For example:

```dart
Map<String, Person> people;

int olderThan(int age) {
  int result = 0;
  for(Person p in people.values)
    if(p.age > age) result++;
  return result;
}

int olderThan2(int age) {
  int result = 0;
  for(MapEntry<String, Person> me in people.entries)
    if(me.value.age > age) result++;
  return result;
}

// Which one is faster: olderThan or olderThan2?
```

If `Map` stores its values internally as `MapEntry` objects, it's possible that `entries` would be just as efficient or even more efficient than `values`. The implementation details of `Map` are buried deep inside Dart libraries, so I wonder if anybody has this knowledge and can shed the light on this subject.

I understand that `Map.entries` gives you access to the key, but I am talking about cases where I don't need to use the key of the entry. I also understand that there are different implementations of `Map`. I am mostly interested in the default implementation, `LinkedHashMap`, but if it would be nice to know if there's a difference between the different `Map` implementations in this aspect.

Comment: My hunch would be that the `.values` version would be slightly faster. Why don't you do some benchmarking to find out?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you iterate over entries a `MapEntry` instance is created for every key-value combination.

If you only need values, iterating `map.values` is more efficient.

Comment: Also `MapEntry` contains `final` values, so you can't change them if you want to.

Comment: So it is basically same to just forEach() except it is final then

Comment: @PaemKacit I don't think that statement applies, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `forEach()` iterates over every collection and is not tied to Map. `entries` or `values` is just about how the `Map` provides a collection of its content. Iterating over that collection is a different step.

Comment: hm.. map.forEach((k, v) => also iterates map\`s key and value but I guess you want to say "when it\`s only iterate inside one map variable" for(MapEntry<String, Person> me in people.entries) is more efficient right

Comment: @PaemKacit I think I get now what you mean. `map.forEach()` works differently, it iterates all keys and all values for each key. So the difference is similar, as it passes key and value as-is, while `entries` creates a new instance of the `MapEntry` class, containing key and value for every key-value pair.

Comment: Which is more efficient you think?? in performance

Comment: @PaemKacit I'd expect omitting the `MapEntry` creation would be more efficient. First it needs to create these object instances, then later the garbage collector needs to dispose them. The iteration work over all keys and values needs to be done in any case.

Answer (score 81):

We should iterate map based on the requirement.

1. If we required to iterate only keys

   `map.keys.forEach((k) => print("Key : $k"));`
2. If we required to iterate only values

   `map.values.forEach((v) => print("Value: $v"));`
3. If we required to iterate both key values.

   `map.forEach((k, v) => print("Key : $k, Value : $v"));`

Comment: Are there performance differences between using the `forEach` function and a regular `for in` loop?

Comment: @jitsm555 for loop is faster than forEach.

Comment: @Kamlesh: Could you please share some points on it? how it is faster?

Comment: @jitsm555 Yes, you can run loop on more than 10M records and note taken time from starting of loop and ending of loop in miliseconds. You will find the difference between for and forEach. Thanks to ask.

Comment: The most concise

Comment: There is another advantage in using the standard for loop instead of forEach. If you do not need to process every record in a list/map you may can stop the loop using break to improve performance. Also linter nowadays recommends using the standard for loop.